# Need clarification in understanding a custom core.logic constraint

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic, functional-logic-progr

I was trying to understand a custom `core.logic` constraint as defined below,

```
(defne lefto
  "x appears to the left of y in collection l."
  [x y l]
  ([_ _ [x . tail]] (membero y tail))
  ([_ _ [_ . tail]] (lefto x y tail)))
```

How to interpret `_` and `.` in the context of `core.logic`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`defne` is a macro that uses a special pattern matching syntax, but behaves similarly to `conde`. (FYI the `e` in each of these stands for "everything" i.e. every clause can contribute.)

- The `_` underscores indicate a value that must be present, but you don't care what it is.
- The `.` indicates a concatenation of items to the left of `.` and the tail of the list to the right of `.`. This is used to bind both individual items of a list and the remainder of the list to different values. (Also see `llist` in core.logic.)

A similar destructuring of a sequence in Clojure would use `&` instead of `.`:

```
(let [[_ _ [_ & tail]] coll] ...)
```

So the following pattern means "we don't care about the first or second input argument, but the third should be a list where we the head is `x` (i.e. equal to the function's `x` input argument) and bind the tail to `tail`":

```
[_ _ [x . tail]]
```

Also note that `tail` can be the empty list here, and you can bind more than one value before the `.`.

Since your example is a recursive goal, it will eventually terminate by either finding `x` before `y`, or it will fail to match either pattern because `l` will (eventually) be the empty list `()` which won't match either case.

## Simpler example

The `membero` definition itself is a simpler example of the same idea:

```
(defne membero
  "A relation where l is a collection, such that l contains x."
  [x l]
  ([_ [x . tail]])
  ([_ [head . tail]]
    (membero x tail)))
```

There are two clauses, each represented by a top-level list `()`:

1. `[_ [x . tail]]` - The first `_` represents the input `x` arg we don't care to *match* on. The `[x . tail]` describes a pattern for the second argument `l` where if `x` is the head of `l`, then this pattern matches and `membero` succeeds.
2. `[_ [head . tail]` - The `_` means the same thing here. But notice we've given a new name to the head of `l`, which only needs to be a non-empty list to satisfy this pattern. If it matches, then we recurse with `(membero x tail)` to continue searching.

Only the first clause can make the goal successful, by finding `x` in a (sub)list of `l`; the second clause is only used to destructure the `head` and `tail` of `l` and recurse.

Here's `membero` translated with `conde` and no pattern matching:

```
(defn memberoo [x l]
  (conde
    [(fresh [a d]
       (conso a d l)
       (== a x))]
    [(fresh [a d]
       (conso a d l)
       (memberoo x d))]))
```

Comment: Thought clojure used `&` because it didn't have dotted list. What is `. ` here? A symbol?

Comment: @Sylwester As the answer sates "." in core logic is concatenation.